# Nesting two sql statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two sql queries, is there anyway to put these into a nested query?

Query 1

```
SELECT
        st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
        st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
        st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
FROM public.table 
ORDER BY x,y,z;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT * FROM public.table TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10))
```

I've tried using a subquery, but it needs an `IN` statement in the `WHERE` clause.

Both queries work individually.

I first want to explode out the geometry and order this by x, y.
With it ordered I then want to use the `BERNOULLI' sampling function.

This needs to be in a single SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

depending on what is the purpose of sampling , you can use random() to get random sampling as well.

```sql
select * from (
SELECT
        st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
        st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
        st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
FROM public.table 
ORDER BY x,y,z
) t order by random() limit 10
```

Comment: This complains of a syntax error due to the `;` I have tried removing this and it still complains, this time at `TABLESAMPLE`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't limit it by a set number, I'm using Bernoulli as a percentage sampler.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to sample.  I would imagine that you want to sample *before* exploding the geometries:

```
SELECT st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
       st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
       st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM public.table TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10)
     ) t
ORDER BY x,y,z;
```

You cannot use `tablesample` on the results of a query.  So, if you want to sample *after* expanding the points, you have basically two options:

- Create a materialized view.
- Generate the random sample yourself.

The second is simple enough:

```
SELECT st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
       st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
       st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
FROM public.table t
WHERE random() < 0.1
ORDER BY x,y,z;
```

Note that this method should be equivalent to the Bernoulli, given that the random value is calculated for each row.

Comment: I need to order by x,y before the Bernouli sampling because we are exploding points out of patches. So I need to sample after exploding.